# How can I install texlive after running rsync with a CTAN mirror?

Tags: installing, texlive-2018

```
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~$ rsync -a --delete rsync://mirrors.shu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /home/alhelal/Downloads/TeXLive
+=============================================================+
|                     Shanghai University                     |
|               -= Open Source Mirror Site =-                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Welcome to Shanghai University Open Source Mirror Site.   |
|                                                             |
|   This mirror is also available on HTTP.                    |
|   HTTP  [https://mirrors.shu.edu.cn]                        |
|   FTP   [ftp://mirrors.shu.edu.cn]                          |
|   RSYNC [rsync://mirrors.shu.edu.cn]                        |
|                                                             |
|   If you have any issues, please contact us :               |
|    - GitHub at https://git.io/shuosc-new                    |
|    - Mail at osc@oa.shu.edu.cn or contact@shuosc.org        |
|    - Mailgroup at http://bi.ly/2rhF0t9                     |
|                                                             |
|   Supported by                                              |
|     Information Technology Office of Shanghai University    |
|     Shanghai University High Performance Computation Center |
|     Shanghai University NITA Lab                            |
|   Maintained by                                             |
|     Shanghai University Open Source Community               |
|                                                             |
+=============================================================+

 Note: Please treat it kindly.
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~$
```

My CTAN mirror repository looks like

```
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/Downloads/TeXLive$ ls
archive                           install-tl-windows.exe.sha512.asc   update-tlmgr-latest.sh.sha512
install-tl                        install-tl.zip                      update-tlmgr-latest.sh.sha512.asc
install-tl-20180526               install-tl.zip.sha512               update-tlmgr-r47457.exe
install-tl-advanced.bat           install-tl.zip.sha512.asc           update-tlmgr-r47457.exe.sha512
install-tl-unx.tar.gz             README.md                           update-tlmgr-r47457.exe.sha512.asc
install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512      tlpkg                               update-tlmgr-r47457.sh
install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512.asc  update-tlmgr-latest.exe             update-tlmgr-r47457.sh.sha512
install-tl-windows.bat            update-tlmgr-latest.exe.sha512      update-tlmgr-r47457.sh.sha512.asc
install-tl-windows.exe            update-tlmgr-latest.exe.sha512.asc
install-tl-windows.exe.sha512     update-tlmgr-latest.sh
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/Downloads/TeXLive$
```

I untar `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` that produced `install-tl-20180526`.
Now, which command I have to run to install texlive?

I tried `./install-tl` that was installing from internet.

```
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/Downloads/TeXLive/install-tl-20180526$ ./install-tl 
Loading http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb

alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/Downloads/TeXLive/install-tl-20180526$ ./install-tl -in-placeLoading http://mirrors.sorengard.com/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
```

Comment: Maybe https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html ?

Answer (score 2):

```
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/Downloads/TeXLive/install-tl-20180526$ ./install-tl -repository ..
```

More information [Command-line install-tl options](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-280003.3)

[image]

Comment: I don't think you even need to specify the local repo. At least I haven't had to in my tests do far. It seems to look to see if there is a tlnet folder in a position relative to where install-tl is, if there is use it, else go online.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to untar the installer, it is already in the same folder as the tar.gz file, just run `./install-tl` then run from the base tlnet folder (often just the root of the tlnet that have been rsynced), the installer will automatically pick up the local repo and use it. There is no need for any options.

Comment: `./install-tl` tries to install from internet.

Comment: @alhelal not if you run it from the same folder that holds the archive folder. You ran it from the install-tl-xxx folder that does not contain the archive folder and thus it runs against an online repo as it does not know about the local repo. But when the installation script runs from the right place it picks up the local repo automatically. It all have to do with relative folders, if the relative test is positive it automatically uses the local repo.

Comment: @alhelal we use this when we install tl from USB, rsync the repo to the USB and run install-tl directly from it, or (more often) copy the contents of the USB to local hard drive and install from there. We have never had to give it any options.