# How to update local TeXLive repository created by rsync?

Tags: installing, updating, texlive-2018

[How can I install texlive after running rsync with a CTAN mirror?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433521/how-can-i-install-texlive-after-running-rsync-with-a-ctan-mirror)

```
rsync -a --delete rsync://mirrors.shu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /home/alhelal/Downloads/TeXLive
```

I make the local repository by above command. That repository was created about 4 months ago. Now, I want to update the local repository so new installation from this local repository reflects the latest and updated TeXLive. And, how can I update the TeXLive after making update in the local repository.

Comment: If you run the same command again, the local repository will be updated. After updating the repository, your local TeXLive installation can be updated using `tlmgr`.

Comment: As mas said. And that is why rsync is a really nice feature.

Comment: @mas $ sudo tlmgr update --all --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/linux/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.